# How can I get the word not character in word range?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to get the word in word via using word vba.

I try this API, but it will only return the serial of character word.

> Doucment.Range(Start, End)

Example:

> This is a book, that I never read it.

---

Input:

> API(2,5)

Output:

> a book, that I

I expect some API can input start's position and end's position and then it will return the string.

Is there any possible?

Comment: In your example, `ActiveDocument.Range(2, 5)` would return the string "his ", that is the 2nd to 5th character.

Comment: @Variatus Yes,It will return "Character ". I need an API that can return the 2nd to 5th "word" in the document because I don't know the start's and end's position of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify a `Range` you need to specify its `Start` and `End`. If you don't know these positions you need to find them. The following code does that.

```
Private Sub SelectWords()

    Dim Rng As Range

    With ActiveDocument
        Set Rng = .Words(2)
        With Rng
            .MoveEnd wdWord, 4
            Debug.Print .Text, .Start, .End
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I point out that this will not work on Chinese "words" which are treated as double-width characters. In English, a word is defined by the character that follows it, in most cases a blank space.